# htaccess mod_rewrite problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to using .htaccess files, so I'm experiencing some errors:

Specifically, I'm having three problems with my mod_rewrite attempts.

I need it to be able to parse limited domains such as `mydomain.com/user` and spit it out as `mydomain.com/elements/scripts/view/?pth=user` and `mydomain.com/user/register-new` as `mydomain.com/elements/scripts/view/?pth=user&ext=register-new`

I currently have:

```
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(.*)$ /elements/scripts/view?pth=$1&ext=$2 [NC,L]
```

I'm not sure whether this works or not, because the `L` flag doesn't seem to be triggered, and it rewrites it, then rewrites it again with `pth=elements&ext=scripts/view` for some reason.

The other problem I have is that I'm able to know how it is being rewritten. I would like the mod_rewrite to be invisible to the user (the browser still displays `mydomain.com/user`), but it currently changes the browser URL to the RewriteRule substitution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this use instead:

```
RewriteRule ^user/?(([^/]+)/?)?$ /elements/scripts/view?pth=user&ext=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

1. Your rule is a way to broad .. and it rewrites to another non-fixed-destination URL (not `/index.php` or something like that -- I cannot tell if `/elements/scripts/view` is a real file ... or another "virtual" path).
2. Because you need URL to only work with `/user` path, I have hardcoded it into a rule -- this makes the rule more specific.
3. This rule needs to be placed in **.htaccess** in website root folder. For any other location it requires some small modifications.
4. Place rule in appropriate place -- **order of rules matters**.

---

*"I'm not sure whether this works or not, because the `L` flag doesn't seem to be triggered, and it rewrites it, then rewrites it again with `pth=elements&ext=scripts/view` for some reason."*

After Apache sees `[L]` flag it stops rewriting further (if rule matches, of course) and goes to **next iteration** starting checking all rules from start -- this is how it works and many people seems to be unaware of this fact.

You may have some other rules that may create such behaviour. But most likely it is done by your current rule -- the pattern (regex) you have is very broad and can catch already rewritten URL (`/elements/scripts/view`) and rewrite it again (pattern **will** match).

---

**UPDATE:**
Based on additional information you have provided these rules can be used instead (1 rule to match all):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)(/?(.*))$ /elements/scripts/view/index.php?pth=$1&ext=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

1. These rules will not rewrite requests to already existing files (e.g. css/jpg/js files).
2. When request will be done to such URL: `mydomain.com/user/register-new`, it will be rewritten to 
   `/elements/scripts/view/index.php?pth=user&ext=register-new` and rewrite goes to next iteration. On next iteration the rule #1 will tell Apache to stop rewriting .. as `/elements/scripts/view/index.php` file does exist. Job done.

If the above is not good for some reasons (e.g. you still need to rewrite requests to physically existing files and serve them dynamically), use these instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/elements/scripts/view/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)(/?(.*))$ /elements/scripts/view/index.php?pth=$1&ext=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` tells Apache to not to rewrite URL if it is already pointing to `/elements/scripts/view/index.php`. Any other URL can be rewritten if it will match pattern.

---

Keep in mind that because I do not know all possible URLs you may have (your URL structure), the pattern *may* require a bit of tweaking.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write very clearly (I've been up all night trying to get this to work). I DO need it to work with other things. Everything other than the elements folder, actually. Is it possible to also make the rewrite invisible to the client?

Comment: @Brian You better split it in few rules. If you want 1 rule matches all -- you can do it as well -- but for this you have to provide **MUCH MORE** information and not 2 URLs only. I have described why your current rule does that "weird" rewrite. It is unclear for me what `/elements/scripts/view` is -- is that physical file (then why no extension) or what? But the original question is answered -- the rule provided will work fine for the URLs mentioned in question. If you want other rules covered provide additional detailed info.

Comment: Basically what I want it to do is be able to take any page directory ('/user','/store','/sillylinks', etc.) and give it to a script in '/elements/scripts/view/index.php' as a $_GET variable 'pth'. The view page looks up the page in a database and displays it to the user based upon what it is, so that pages can be edited without having to have ftp access. The second variable ($ext) is for any additional commands to give the page, such as '/user/submit-new' would be parsed as 'show the user page, with the commands to submit a new user account'

Comment: I see. I will update my answer with solution (I may not do it straight away as I have other tasks at the moment, but I will surely do it today -- stay tuned).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I had to tweak it slightly, but it seems to work now. Thanks!